# External Harddrive not recognized

Tags: usb, hard-drive, usb-drive, external-hdd, drive

I have a 500gb usb harddrive. It works with other computers and I have swapped the cable around with others. I have ran    dmesg    and it says that a seagate is inserted but it still does not come up. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try mounting the drive manually.

1. get the device name either from dmesg or 'fdisk -l'
2. 'sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/user/usbdrive'

/dev/sdb1 could be something else.